# Apache server is running but httpd is not running

Tags: apache

I'm facing a weird problem. When I access the web-accessible directory of my server via domain linked to it. It says:-

```
Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

When I run this command on my server (via putty), it displays few processes ids demonstrating that Apache web server is running (correct me).

```
root@...:~# pgrep apache
4733
13505
13506
13507
13508
13686
14199
17672
```

But when I run this command, it says that httpd: unrecognized service

```
root@...:~# service httpd status
httpd: unrecognized service
```

Some other commands output:-

```
root@...:~# ps aux|grep -i http
root     29401  0.0  0.0   6460   792 pts/0    S+   02:21   0:00 grep --color=auto -i http
```

How can I fix this?

Update:-

```
root@...:~# chkconfig --list | grep httpd
-bash: chkconfig: command not found

root@...:~# find / -name httpd*
/var/www/vhosts/lvps5-35-241-230.dedicated.hosteurope.de/httpdocs
/var/www/vhosts/.skel/0/httpdocs
/opt/psa/var/httpd_restart
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/httpd.exp
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/fr/programs/httpd.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/pt-br/programs/httpd.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/da/programs/httpd.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/zh-cn/programs/httpd.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/tr/programs/httpd.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/en/programs/httpd.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/ja/programs/httpd.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/ko/programs/httpd.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/de/programs/httpd.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/es/programs/httpd.html
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/httpd.conf.gz
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-manual.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-languages.conf.gz
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-ssl.conf.gz
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-mpm.conf.gz
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-default.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-dav.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/original/extra/httpd-info.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-manual.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-languages.conf.gz
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf.gz
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf.gz
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-default.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-dav.conf
/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-info.conf
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
/etc/apache2/httpd.pem

root@...:~# whereis httpd
httpd:

root@...:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise

root@...:~# ls /etc/init.d
README             hostname           network-interface-container  plymouth-upstart-bridge  rc              spamassassin            udevtrigger
apache2            hwclock            network-interface-security   portmap                  rc.local        ssh                     umountfs
bind9              hwclock-save       networking                   portmap-wait             rcS             stop-bootlogd           umountnfs.sh
bluetooth          keymap.sh          ondemand                     postfix                  reboot          stop-bootlogd-single    umountroot
bootlogd           killprocs          passwd                       procps                   rpcbind-boot    sudo                    unattended-upgrades
console-screen.sh  klogd              pc-remote                    psa                      rsync           sw-cp-server            urandom
courier-imap       module-init-tools  plymouth                     psa-firewall             saslauthd       sysklogd                wide-dhcpv6-client
cron               modules_dep.sh     plymouth-log                 psa-firewall-forward     screen-cleanup  udev                    x11-common
dbus               mongodb            plymouth-ready               psa-spamassassin         sendsigs        udev-fallback-graphics  xinetd
fetchmail          mysql              plymouth-splash              quota                    single          udev-finish
halt               network-interface  plymouth-stop                quotarpc                 skeleton        udevmonitor

root@...:~# ls /etc/xinetd.d
chargen  daytime  discard  echo  ftp_psa  poppassd_psa  time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is httpd listed in your /etc/xinetd, /etc/xinet.d, /etc/xinitd.d, or /etc/init.d directory? Also use chkconfig to see if httpd is listed.

```
# chkconfig --list | grep httpd
```

If it's not:

```
# find / -name httpd*
```

or

```
# whereis httpd
```

to find where it might be installed at. Then I'd make a symbolic link to it in (depending on you linux / unix flavor) /etc/xinetd, /etc/xinet.d, /etc/xinitd.d, or /etc/init.d.

Comment: I've listed all the commands you want to know in the question. I shall be very grateful to you if you can help me out in this. Ubuntu version (also listed in the updated answer) is 12.04.5